# Scale text to fit it's container in modern Angular

Tags: css, angular

```
<div class="text-container">foo</div>

.text-container {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

How to make text inside `text-container` fit within it? No of the solutions I found seems to work in modern Angular.

Comment: @Manjuboyz It's a known problem in css, that text size isn't affected by its container height and width, because it's size can be set only by font-size property. There are jQuery libraries that automatically calculate and set font-size value based on its container size, however I'm looking for solution more native to Angular.

Comment: so now I get it, when the container size increases you want the content in the class(font) should also be increase/decreased ?

Comment: @Manjuboyz Yea, exactly

Comment: something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/gah1uozs/18/